# Multiple Contained UICollectionViewController pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a app that will use multiple `UICollectionViewControllers` in a container view like this:

`MasterViewController > (x2) Container Views > UICollectionViewController > UICollectionView > UICollectionViewCell`

I've had to do this because I need the sections(each of the collection views in my case) to be scrollable vertically. Otherwise I would used a single Collection View and use the sections to my favor. This proves to be a little tricky because so far I've had to make Master Controller the data source of each of the Collection Views. Which means I have to implement if statements to check which collection view is asking for the data. Here is a sample:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"section1"]) {
        self.topLeft = [segue destinationViewController];
        [self setDelegate:self.topLeft]; // set topleft delegate
        self.topLeft.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"section2"]) {
        self.topRight = [segue destinationViewController];
        self.topRight.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    }
}
```

How can the 2 contained controllers coordinate with my master controller? Right now I don't even know why I have them. Currently I have a gesture recognizer attached to the master controller because I wanna drag and drop between Collection View Controllers. I need to constantly check which Collection View the touch is above because I want to animate items out of the way when I add one to a collection, but it seems like I have to search thru all the collection views each time the `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` is called. Is there any way I can use delegation to make everything more modular right the the master controller is doing all the work.

Thanks

Comment: Why does the master controller need to be the data source? Why can't each collection view controller be its own data source?

Comment: Idk lol. Well I thought about it and I was leaving the two collection controllers doing nothing. So maybe I can just just make the controllers their own data source and have Master Controller set the data property on each of them, making the Master Controller ultimately responsible but making it easier to manage. Also I'm having trouble getting their positing with `CGRectContainsPoint` only one collection view return when the point is over it and it's all messed up, any ideas, thanks again for the help.